# Performing Difference in Pair of row of data

Tags: r

My Data Frame is:

```
df:

one     two     three
a       8       x
a       12      y
b       9       x
b       3       y
```

and result should be like:

```
one     two
a       4
b       6
```

can you please help me..

Comment: is the difference expected to be absolute or has to be x-y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(two~one, data=df, FUN=function(i) abs(diff(i)))
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="one     two     three
a       8       x
                 a       12      y
                 b       9       x
                 b       3       y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

 df <- data.frame(one = factor(c("a", "a", "b", "b")),
                 two = c(8,12,9,3),
                 three = factor(c("x", "y", "x", "y")))

 answer <- df %>% group_by(one) %>% summarise(two = abs(diff(two)))

 > answer
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

     one   two
   (fctr) (dbl)
 1      a     4
 2      b     6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(two = abs(diff(two))), .(one)]
```

With `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, 'one', summarise, two = abs(diff(two)))
  one two
1   a   4
2   b   6
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans, but is there any other way to get result without data.table library..

Comment: You can also use `plyr` package. See the updated answer.